# pass parameter in the body spring boot and angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm working with spring boot and angular and I passed as a parameter in get request  in the body

```
 @GetMapping("/parAdresse")
    public List<Object> parAdresse(@RequestBody String adresse) {
        
          return dis.finddis(adresse) ; 
          
 }
```

How I can do the same in the front?

```
  pieChart(add: string) {

return  this.http.get("http://localhost:9095/distri/parAdresse");
   
  }
```

Comment: don't think GET request will work with `@RequestBody`, did you mean `@PathVariable`

Comment: I don't want that the parameter shows in the url

Comment: It is not possible to send the request body in GET request, either you can pass as path variable or query in GET request or you can send as request body in POST method, and returning Object type is not a good practice it should be some concrete DTO/VM. @MariemKAROUI

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp refer this resource to understand more about HTTP methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

backend

```
 @GetMapping("/parAdresse")
            public List<Object> parAdresse( @RequestParam String adresse) {
                
                  return dis.finddis(adresse) ; 
                  
         }
```

front

```
pieChart(add: string) {
    let queryParams = new HttpParams();
    queryParams = queryParams.append("adresse","TUNIS");
    return  this.http.get("http://localhost:9095/distri/parAdresse", {params:queryParams});
   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`GET` methods cannot have request `body`, you can convert Java action into `POST` method.

```
 @PostMapping("/parAdresse")
```

And then pass the information inside post method `body` from angular.

```
return this.http.post("http://localhost:9095/distri/parAdresse", {
  adresse: add
});
```